# How to configure role_model with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-admin, role

Does anyone have any experience with configuring [role_model](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) with [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)?

I want it to say role of a User is Admin, Customer, etc in the admin section instead of 1, 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

After a little time I got it figured out, and just thought I'd share here.

If you add this to your rails_admin config section for the model that has the roles.

```
  configure :roles_mask, :enum do
    label { "Role" }
    enum { User.valid_roles.map{|role| ["#{role.capitalize}", User.mask_for(role)] }.to_h }
  end
```

It doesn't cover the situation where you might want a user to be two roles at the same time, but I don't need that right now. If anyone works that out feel free to post it here too!